# GCP DataFlow Data Access Audit Logs - How can I enable data access logs for a Dataflow Job?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-logging

In Google official document(https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/audit-logging) it is mentioned that you have to explicitly enable the data access logs.

To receive data access logs we have to do the following

1. In the Data Access audit logs configuration table, select one or more Google Cloud services from the Service column.
2. In the Log Types tab, select the Data Access audit log types that you want to enable for your selected services.
3. Click Save.

I am not able to find Dataflow service in the Data Access audit logs configuration table.
Please let me know how can we receive data access logs for dataflow.

I have tried to enable the data access logs from Data Access audit logs configuration table but not able to find dataflow service.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable

[Data Access logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNH8b.png)

[Enable Data Access Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdYYt.png)
[Don't have dataflow service available in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ArFc.png)

Comment: The problem is I am not able to enable data access logs for Dataflow job

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the scenario on a Cloud Skill Boost Lab. The steps I did were:

1. Enabling the Dataflow API
2. Go to IAM > Audit Logs

There, I searched for the Dataflow service using the filter `Service:data*`. However, as you well reported, I wasn't able to find this service.

Double checking the documentation, I can see how the [Dataflow Audit Logs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/audit-logging#available-logs) redirects to the [Operations Suite Data Access article](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable) where it details the steps for enabling the Data Access Audit Logs, as you kindly shared.

I have written a Feedback about the documentation article pointing to the Operations Suite instructions, sharing how this service is not listed even after enabling its API.

Upon further inspection of the public documentation, you can inspect the Dataflow Audit Logs by querying for the following [resource types](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/audit-logging#resource_types) on the Logging Explorer:

- `resource_type="dataflow_step"`
- `resource_type="audited_resource"`

Moreover, the Dataflow audit logs use the service name `dataflow.googleapis.com` and the Data Pipelines `datapipelines.googleapis.com`, for further filtering. You can get more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/audit-logging#service_name)

I hope the information provided could help you inspect your Dataflow audit logs. Let's see if the Feedback team shares more insights about this issue.